# Complex Differentiability Limit Definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have $f(x+iy)=y^2$. This satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations for all $z_0=(x,0)$. Now I want to check whether $f$ is differentiable for all $(x,0)$. So I use the definition, taking the limit as $h$ tends to $0$, and letting $h=a+bi$:

$$\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}=\frac{f(x+a+bi)-f(x)}{a+ib}=\frac{b^2}{a+ib}$$

But how am I meant to compute the limit of $\frac{b^2}{a+ib}$ as $h$ tends to $0$, which I suppose means $(a,b)$ tends to $(0,0)$. Can someone help me do this using the definition please? Thanks.

Comment: Your f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y) where u and v are the real and imaginary parts of f(x+iy). The Cauchy-Riemann equations are that ∂u/∂x = ∂v/∂y and ∂u/∂y = -∂v/∂x. Have you really shown that they hold?

Comment: @DanAsimov Well $u=y^2$ and $v=0$. You get $0 = 0$ and $2y = -0$ so they hold whenever $y=0$ and $x$ is any real number. So the cauchy riemann equations hold for all $(x,0)$?

Comment: While the CR equations hold at every point on the real axis, the do not hold on any open set around such points.  And hence $y^2$ is not holomorphic.  This means that $y^2$ is nowhere complex differentiable.

Comment: @MarkViola I am confused because the other poster says different as the limit tends to $0$ which is finite so it should be differentiable everywhere on the real axis?

Comment: @MarkViola They are not using the holomorphic $\iff$ complex differentiable in a neighbourhood definition.

Comment: @JulioPuerta Who are "they?"

Comment: Original poster, unknown gender so the correct form is 'they'.

Comment: @JulioPuerta The title is "Complex Differentiability Limit Definition."  And what do you believe is the definition of "complex differentiable?"  The person who posted the question might not understand the issue here.

Comment: A complex function $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$ iff $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0} \dfrac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists.

Comment: @JulioPuerta Yes that is the definition I was using, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If $x\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}\lim_{z\to x}\frac{\operatorname{Im}^2z-\operatorname{Im}^2x}{z-x}&=\lim_{z\to x}\frac{\operatorname{Im}^2z}{z-x}\\&=\lim_{z\to x}\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z-x)}{z-x}\operatorname{Im}z\end{align}(since $x\in\Bbb R$ and therefore $\operatorname{Im}x=0$). But $\lim_{z\to x}\operatorname{Im}z=0$ and $\left|\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z-x)}{z-x}\right|\leqslant1$ for each $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{x\}$. Therefore$$\lim_{z\to x}\frac{\operatorname{Im}(z-x)}{z-x}\operatorname{Im}z=0.$$In other words, your function is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: It is not Complex Differentiable anywhere.

Comment: @MarkViola It *is* complex differentiable at the points of $\Bbb R$ (and only at those points).

Comment: That is not complex differentiable.  Complex differentiability applies to open sets around a point or on the sphere.  It is tantamount to differentiability on $\mathbb{R^2}$.  It is synonymous with analyticity.

Comment: @MarkViola Where did you get that idea? Take,for instance, Serge Lang's *Complex Analysis*. It says: “Let $U$ be an open set, and let $z$ be a point of $U$. Let $f$ be a function on $U$. We say that $f$ is complex differentiable at $z$ if the limit$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h$$ exists.” Are you claiming that the function $\operatorname{Im}^2$ is *not* differentiable at the points of $\Bbb R$ according to *this* definition?

Comment: Hi Jose my friend.  We are using different definitions.   I am suggesting that the definition of Complex Differentiability is not as Lang's book suggests.  As others define it, it is synonymous with being analytic (or holomorphic).    Does that make sense.  Having a derivative and being differentiable are two different things

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $$0\leq\left|\dfrac{b^2}{a+ib}\right|^2=\dfrac{b^4}{a^2+b^2}\leq \dfrac{b^4}{b^2}=b^2\to 0,$$ so $$\dfrac{b^2}{a+ib}\to 0$$
and $f$ is differentiable in all points of the form $(x,0)$.

Edit: It could also be used that $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+ iv(x,y)$ is complex differentiable at $x_0+iy_0$ iff $u$ and $v$ are differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ and they verify the CR equations; I understood the purpose of the question was to prove that $f$ is holomorphic using exclusively the limit definition.

Comment: So my working was all correct prior to that? Is there another way of solving this question using the definition without replacing $h$ with $a+ib$. Seems a bit long.

Comment: Yes, the working was correct. As the function is given in function of the coordinates (that is, in $x$ and $y$) instead of directly in function of the complex number $z$ the most natural way to work this out is using coordinates for $h$ too.

Comment: Thanks. Is it okay to use the absolute value as in my expression I didn'thave an absolute value.

Comment: I am using the complex norm, not the absolute value; as $a_n\to 0$ iff $|a_n|\to 0$ (per definition)

Comment: For the statement you said in the “edit part”, isn’t that only true if the points are part of an open set?

Comment: $f$ must be defined in an open set (in this case $\mathbb{C}$), but the conditions may only be satisfied at one point.

Comment: But for $(x,0)$ there doesn’t exist an open set around it. That’s why I used limit definition instead

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ is open and contains $x_0$... We do not need CR equations to hold for points in a open set, only in $(x,0)$

Comment: I was using the theorem that if $S$ is open and $f$ maps $S$ to $\mathbb C$, and you write $f = u + iv$, and the partial order partial derivatives exist and are continuous for all points in $S$, and that the cauchy riemann equations are satisfied for all points in $S$, then $f$ must be differentiator for all points in $S$.

Comment: And that in our example $S$ $= (x,0)$

Comment: Well, that is a weaker form of the Theorem. Then, it's better to use the limit definition as we have already done.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will close the question now. One final question, just because I think I’m being stupid, obviously the entire complex plane $(x,y)$ is open right and I’m not tripping?

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{C}$ is open